# Calulating the orthogonal complement of the sp(1,-1,1) and the second complement.

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, spectral-theory, orthogonality

I am confused on how to find the orthogonal compliment for $M=\operatorname{sp}(1,-1,1)$ where $M \subset \Bbb{R} ^3$. My current working is letting $\mathbf x=(x,y,z)$ and then taking $0=x-y+z$ such that $y=x+z$.

From here note that $M^\perp=\operatorname{sp}(1,2,1)$ but I am unsure whether this is correct and what it is telling me. I am then tasked to find $(M^{\perp})^{\perp}$ which I have no idea how to find. Also if anyone could recommend any books on spectral theory that would be great!

Comment: You have two free variables in your equation, so you should expect its solution space to be two-dimensional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $M^{\perp}$ should be $2$-dimensional since $M\subset\mathbb{R}^{3}$ is one-dimensional. You correctly noted that
$$M^{\perp}=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^{3}:y=x+z\},$$
from which it follows that
$$M^{\perp}=\text{Span}\{(1,1,0),(0,1,1)\}.$$

Next, it is true in general that $(M^{\perp})^{\perp}=M$.

Comment: Thank you. I might be being daft but why should we expect $M^\perp$ to be two dimensional?

Comment: For any linear subspace $V\subset\mathbb{R}^{3}$, it is true that $\dim(V)+\dim(V^{\perp})=\dim(\mathbb{R}^{3})=3$. So if $V$ is one-dimensional, then its orthogonal complement in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ is two-dimensional. Geometrically, the orthogonal complement of a line through the origin is a plane through the origin.

Comment: Ok, I see - that helps a lot! Cheers